# how to combine data from 2 list of lists to form a single JSON in python

Tags: python, json, list, csv

I have 2 `csv` files(semicolon delimited) with following structure and sample data:

**File 1:**

```
qid;question
1.0;How can I find specific content
2.0;How do I modify content
2.0;How can I edit items
2.0;I need to change some answers
3.0;How do I troubleshoot and fix problems
```

**File 2:**

```
qid;answer
1.0;Use the Filter feature to filter the items
2.0;Use the test tool to find your existing documents and edit them
3.0;Use the test tool to test a document
```

Now what I want to do is form  a `JSON` structure which contains data from both documents to form following sample structure:

```
{
   "qna": [
      {
         "qid": "1.0",
         "q": [
            "How can I find specific content"
         ],
         "a": "Use the Filter feature to filter the items."

      },
      {
         "qid": "2.0",
         "q": [
            "How do I modify content","How do I edit items","I need to change some answers"
         ],
         "a": "Use the test tool to find your existing documents and edit them."
      },
      {
         "qid": "3.0",
         "q": [
            "How do I troubleshoot and fix problems"
         ],
         "a": "Use the test tool to test a document"

      }
]
}
```

As you can see what this `JSON` contains a `list of list` within `qna` field. Each of the items in this `list of list` contains the `qid`, list of questions matching same `qid`, and answer matching the `qid`.

I wrote this code where I am reading these 2 `csv` files and forming 2 `list of lists`:

```
qid_question_list = {}
qid_answer_list = {}

reader1 = csv.reader(csv_file1, delimiter=';')

next(reader1)

reader2 = csv.reader(csv_file2, delimiter=';')

next(reader2)

for qid,question in reader1:
    if qid not in qid_question_list:
        qid_question_list[qid] = list()
    qid_question_list[qid].append(question)

for qid,answer in reader2:
    if qid not in qid_answer_list:
        qid_answer_list[qid] = list()
    qid_answer_list[qid].append(answer)
```

When I execute above I get following 2 `lists`:

**qid_question_list**

```
{'1.0': ['How can I find specific content'], '2.0': ['How do I modify content','How do I edit items','I need to change some answers'], '3.0': ['How do I troubleshoot and fix problems']}
```

**qid_answer_list**

```
{'1.0': ['Use the Filter feature to filter the items'], '2.0': ['Use the test tool to find your existing documents and edit them'], '3.0': ['Use the test tool to test a document']}
```

Now I am not able to determine how can I club these 2 `list of lists` to form the desired `JSON` structure shown above?

Comment: are the semicolons supposed to be commas in file 1 and file 2?

Comment: @James no its a semicolon delimited file.

Comment: what about the header?  as-written it is comma delimited

Comment: @James apologies. that was a typo. Headers are also semicolon delimited. I have edited my post. I am anyways skipping the header when reading files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you've the two dicts handy

```
l1={'1.0': ['How can I find specific content'], '2.0': ['How do I modify content','How do I edit items','I need to change some answers'], '3.0': ['How do I troubleshoot and fix problems']}

l2={'1.0': ['Use the Filter feature to filter the items'], '2.0': ['Use the test tool to find your existing documents and edit them'], '3.0': ['Use the test tool to test a document']}

l = [ {"qid": k, "q": v, "a": l2[k]} for k,v in l1.items() ]

q={'qna': l }

print(q)
```

Output

```
{'qna': [{'qid': '1.0', 'q': ['How can I find specific content'], 'a': ['Use the Filter feature to filter the items']}, {'qid': '2.0', 'q': ['How do I modify content', 'How do I edit items', 'I need to change some answers'], 'a': ['Use the test tool to find your existing documents and edit them']}, {'qid': '3.0', 'q': ['How do I troubleshoot and fix problems'], 'a': ['Use the test tool to test a document']}]}
```

Comment: values in `a` are not supposed to be list. Its a single string value

Comment: @user2916886 I noticed that and thought it would be better to keep it in list. scenario where `a` has multiple values? It can be kept as string as well.

Comment: in my use case `a` will always have single value.

Comment: @user2916886 you can use `"a": l2[k][0]` in that case.

Comment: one doubt that i have is that if I have to pass this JSON output then would I need to use `json.loads()`?

Comment: @user2916886 I'm not sure if I've understood your question correctly. `json.loads()` returns an object from a json object.

Comment: I have to pass the output i am getting to an API call as a JSON object. So would I need to do `json.loads(q)` for that right?

Comment: @user2916886 I think so but not sure about that, sorry.